# Java internal message queue /JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms, message-queue

I have a web application i am rewriting that currently performs a large amount of audit data sql writes. Every step of user interaction results in a method being executed that writes some information to a database. 
This has the potential to impact users by causing the interaction to stop due to database problems.

Ideally I want to move this is a message based approach where if data needs to be written it is fired off too a queue, where a consumer picks these up and writes them to the database. It is not essential data, and loss is acceptable if the server goes down.

I'm just a little confused if I should try and use an embedded JMS queue and broker, or a Java queue. Or something I'm not familiar with (suggestions?)

What is the best approach?

More info: 
The app uses spring and is running on websphere 6. All message communication is local, it will not talk to another server.

Comment: You can use ActiveMQ..

Comment: @Anubhab, ActiveMQ embedded in WebSphere when there is already a JMS broker running, really??

Answer (score 1):

I think logging with JMS is overkill, and especially if loggin is the only reason for using JMS.

Have a look at [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html), you can log directly to the database. If performance is your concern you can log asynchronously using Logback.

If you still want to go JMS way then Logback has JMS [Queue](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/net/JMSQueueAppender.html) & [Topic](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/net/JMSTopicAppender.html) appenders

Comment: To be clear, logging is writing audit information( user x did this at this time) to a SQL database. I'm not referring to application logging.

Comment: my answer should go for both audit or application logging :)

Answer (score 1):

A plain queue will suffice based on your description of the problem. You can have a fixed size queue and discard messages if it fills too quickly since you say they are not critical.

Things to consider:

- Is this functionality required by other apps too, now or in the
  future.
- Are the rate of producing messages so huge that it can start
  consuming lot of heap memory when large number of users are logged
  in. Important if messages should not be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is best practice inside a Java EE container however.

Since you already run on a WebSphere machine, you do have a JMS broker going (SIBus). The easiest way to kick off asynchronous things are to send JMS messages and have a MDB reading them off - and doing database insertions. You might have some issues spawning own threads in WebSphere can still utilise the initial context for JNDI resources.

In a non Java EE case, I would have used a something like a plain LinkedBlockingQueue or any blocking queue, and just have a thread polling that queue for new messages to insert into a database.

Comment: I am aware of the issues around spawing threads in WebSphere - but have found a way around this using the worker pool. I am not familar with SIBus - can this be used as an internal broker? So just create an internal queue and reference it via JNDI? Do you have any more references around using SIBus in this case - from a quick google I can only find highlevel IBM information

Comment: This came up top of a google search and covers what you need: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0504_reinitz/0504_reinitz.html

Answer (score 0):

I would uses JMS queue only if there are different servers involved. So in your case I would do it in simple plain pure java with some Java queue.